# Python's xml.etree getiterator equivalent to C#

Tags: c#, python, xml

I have this XML file : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10773282/2011/perf.xml

[image]

It has two Class elements as is marked. I need to get two nodes with C#.

With Python, I can easily get them with etree.ElementTree as follows.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element

tree = et.parse("perf.xml")
tss = tree.getiterator('Class')

for elem in tss:
    tss_name =  elem.find('ClassKeyName')
    print tss_name.text

>> helloclass.exe
>> helloclass.exeFpga::TestMe
```

[image]

How can I do the same thing with C#?

### SOLVED

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

namespace HIR {
  class Dummy {

    static void Main(String[] argv) {

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("perf.xml");
        var res = from p in doc.Root.Elements("Module").Elements("NamespaceTable").Elements("Class").Elements("ClassKeyName")  select p.Value;

        foreach (var val in res) {
            Console.WriteLine(val.ToString());
        }
    }
  }
}

>> helloclass.exe
>> helloclass.exeFpga::TestMe
```

Or

```
foreach (var elem in elems) {
    var res = elem.Elements("ClassKeyName").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(res[0].Value);
}
```

Comment: var res = from p in doc.Root.Elements("Module").Elements("NamespaceTable").Elements("Class").Elements("ClassKeyName") select p.Value;

Comment: The xml file on dropbox is no longer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try Linq to XML... Quite easy to use:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(filename);
var res = from p in xml.Root.Elements("Class").Elements("ClassKeyName") select p.Value;
```

Comment: How to use the res variable to get the string?

Comment: the res variable is a IEnumerable<string>, so a foreach (var res2 in res)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
using System.Xml;
// ...
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filename);
var matches = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Class/ClassKeyName");
```