# Accessing Linq to XML query results with [] in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008423/pythons-xml-etree-getiterator-equivalent-to-c), the Linq to XML query result are accessed with iterator as follows.

```
foreach (var elem in elems) {
    var res = elem.Elements("ClassKeyName");

    foreach (var e in res) {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Value);
    }
}
```

Can I access the result with []? For example, I want to use as follows,

```
foreach (var elem in elems) {
    var res = elem.Elements("ClassKeyName");
    Console.WriteLine(res[0].Value);
}
```

However, I got this error message

```
xmlparse.cs(18,34): error CS0021: 
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type
`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd just have to convert the results to an indexable type, such as a list:

```
foreach (var elem in elems) {
    List<XElement> res = elem.Elements("ClassKeyName").ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(res[0].Value);
}
```

(You can still use `var` if you want - I've just given it an explicit type to make it clearer in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the first, you can `res.First().Value`. If you need the n-th element `res.Skip(n - 1).Value` (so the first element is `res.Skip(0).Value`, the second `res.Skip(1).Value`...).

The big question is WHY? What do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about First(), actually, this was what I wanted to get. However, ToList() works fine, and it's good to know about it either.